# Overide Magento Enterprise Core Observer Method

Tags: php, magento, enterprise

Im Trying to over ride several methods located in the Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Observer class. In the core config this Observer is defined as

```
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <catalog_product_save_custom_redirect>
                    <class>enterprise_catalog/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductCustomRedirect</method>
                </catalog_product_save_custom_redirect>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
```

In my enxtension app/code/local/Extensioname/Redirects/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Extensioname_Redirects>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Extensioname_Redirects>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Extensioname_Redirects>
                <class>Extensioname_Redirects_Model_Observer</class>
            </Extensioname_Redirects>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <extensioname_redirects>
                        <class>Extensioname_Redirects_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductCustomRedirect</method>
                    </extensioname_redirects>
                 </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

in app/code/local/Extensioname/Redirects/Model/Observer.php

```
class Extensioname_Redirects_Model_Observer extends Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Observer
{
    public function saveProductCustomRedirect(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

But the core observer is still firing saveProductCustomRedirects and my extension is doing nothing. Please help

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: if anyone is having troubles with this my problem came down to not rewriting the core observer in my extensions config. Also word casing played an issue in that the extension started working once all of my xml tags where changed to lowercase within the the models node. My updated extensions config is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Extension>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Extension>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>

            <my_extension>
                <class>My_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
            </my_extension>
            <!-- Updated here to rewrite core observer
                 Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Observer -->
            <enterprise_catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>My_Extension_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_catalog>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_extension>
                        <class>My_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductCustomRedirect</method>
                    </my_extension>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```